# mplayer dumpstream sometimes fails

Tags: windows, video, mplayer

I'm trying to rip the video at http://videolectures.net/ecml07_getoor_isr/, so I can play it at a faster speed.  I paste http://193.2.4.216/2007/pascal/ecml07_warsaw/getoor_lise/ecml07_getoor_isr_01.wmv into a firefox browser in Windows and MediaPlayer plays the thing.  However if I try mplayer -dumpstream, it gets stuck into an infinite loop trying to play the file.

If I use wget to download the link, I get a small text file which basically points to the same URL.  How can I get mplayer to download this stream?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Referer:` header to wget?

Comment: Tried that..nope.

Comment: I checked and the stream doesn't exist anymore (using normal windows media player)
Has it moved to a different location I can test ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make the mplayer plugin capture a stream, but mplayer itself can capture streams fairly well.  Try running from the command line.  Either:

```
wget < your url > -O - | mplayer -cache 8192 -
```

or

```
mplayer < your url > -dumpstream -dumpfile < out file >
```

Comment: mplayer puts these in an infinite loop.

Comment: I think the wget approach may work.  I seem to be missing an avisynth.dll for windows I would need to actually play the lecture at your URl, however, the wget works & mplayer starts.  Calling mplayer directly does cause it to get stuck in a loop.  I'm 99% sure it's because when mplayer makes it's request, the response has `?MSWMExt=.asf.`  tacked on the end.  That is going to cause mplayer alot of grief, but I don't know how to prevent it.